# Getting duplicate content and partial content while trying to get only incremental data for a file

Tags: c#, file

I have a file `test.txt` which is continuously feed with data by a 3rd party application.

Now my requirement is get the data of this file every 1 hour and content should be only incremental, no duplicate data.

Example -

1. First run of my application, if data for `test.txt` is below...

   ```
   line 1.........
   line 2.........
   line 3.........
   data is continuously feeding
   ```

   then data of my file `first_run_file.txt` will be...

   ```
   line 1.........
   line 2.........
   line 3.........
   ```
2. Now after 1 hour, if data for `test.txt` is below...

   ```
   line 1.........
   line 2.........
   line 3.........
   line 4.........
   line 5.........
   ```

   data is continuously feeding

   then data of my file `second_run_file.txt` will be...

   ```
   line 4.........
   line 5.........
   ```

With below piece of code where I'm using `File.Seek`, either my resultant file has partial content or has duplicate data. what could be the best way to read file and get only incremental bytes?

```
byte[] arrBytes;
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    //save this value to store current stream lenght
    var fileSizeInBytes = fileStream.Length;

    //skip the bytes
    fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    //next time onward I'm using fileSizeInBytes for skip bytes, so that I only get incremental data
    //fileStream.Seek(fileSizeInBytes, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    arrBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];

    fileStream.ReadAsync(arrBytes, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

    File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.txt", arrBytes);
}
```

1. `first_run_file.txt` file may have partial bytes like entry,

   ```
   line 1.........
   line 2.........
   line 3.........
   li
   ```

   Here `line 4` is not complete in resultant file.
2. `second_run_file.txt` file may have partial bytes like entry,

   ```
   line 2.........
   line 3.........
   line 4.........
   line 5.........
   ```

   Here `line 2....` and `line 3....` is duplicate which also present in `first_run_file.txt`

Comment: Have you thought about creating a Class that represents the exact file / data structure? from there load all the data into a List<sting> and write conditional statements that check the file against what ever text or literal content you are expecting..

Comment: the said issue I observed only when data read and write at same time. Let say there is some write on file and the 3rd party app stop and then when I'm trying to read for incremental data then no issues.

Comment: So why would you have 2 different processes reading and or updating the same file ? I am just curious.. sounds like you need to do multi-threaded process for this but risky in my opinion based on your use case..

Comment: A legacy application keeps feeding data to the file, now my application just tries to read the data in a incremental fashion for a different purpose.